# code tag and pre css in html not functioning properly

Tags: html, css

in html i am using the code tag as below and also i am using the css as shown below :-

```
<style type="text/css">
    code { white-space: pre; }
</style>


<code>
    public static ArrayList<File> getFiles(File[] files){
        ArrayList<File> _files = new ArrayList<File>();    
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            if (files[i].isDirectory())
                _files.addAll(getFiles(new File(files[i].toString()).listFiles()));
            else 
                _files.add(files[i]);
        return _files;
    } 

    public static File[] getAllFiles(File[] files) {
        ArrayList<File> fs = getFiles(files);
        return (File[]) fs.toArray(new File[fs.size()]); 
    }
</code>
```

When i use the code tag as shown above some part of the code is missing in the html page when viewed. when view the above html page the output is as shown below:-

```
public static ArrayList getFiles(File[] files){
        ArrayList _files = new ArrayList();    
        for (int i=0; i fs = getFiles(files);
        return (File[]) fs.toArray(new File[fs.size()]); 
    }
```

In the first method some part is missing and the second method is not appearing at all. what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: have a look here  as to what else to do with PRE to make it behave like XMP used to http://www.the-pope.com/listin.html

Answer (score 1):

You have these `<File>` inside your `<code>` tag, you need to convert them to `&lt;` and `&gt;` html entities

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7sJBp/)

```
<code>
    public static ArrayList&lt;File&gt; getFiles(File[] files){
        ArrayList&lt;File&gt; _files = new ArrayList&lt;File&gt;();    
        for (int i=0; i&lt;files.length; i++)
            if (files[i].isDirectory())
                _files.addAll(getFiles(new File(files[i].toString()).listFiles()));
            else 
                _files.add(files[i]);
        return _files;
    } 

    public static File[] getAllFiles(File[] files) {
        ArrayList&lt;File&gt; fs = getFiles(files);
        return (File[]) fs.toArray(new File[fs.size()]); 
    }
</code>
```

Answer (score -1):

As already identified by Mr. Alien, you have characters being interpreted as markup inside your `<code>` block.

As an alternative to escaping lots of characters, providing your code does not include the string `</script`, you can exploit the parsing and (non)execution behaviour of the `<script>` element like this:

```
<code>
    <script type="text/x-code">
    public static ArrayList<File> getFiles(File[] files){
        ArrayList<File> _files = new ArrayList<File>();    
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            if (files[i].isDirectory())
                _files.addAll(getFiles(new File(files[i].toString()).listFiles()));
            else 
        _files.add(files[i]);
        return _files;
    } 

    public static File[] getAllFiles(File[] files) {
        ArrayList<File> fs = getFiles(files);
        return (File[]) fs.toArray(new File[fs.size()]); 
    }
    </script>
</code>
```

with this CSS:

```
script[type=text\/x-code] { 
  display: block; 
  white-space: pre; 
  line-height: 20px; 
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

See JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZuPm/3/

---

Update: In the comments, RoToRa raises some interesting points about the "correctness" of this approach, and I thank RoToRa for them.

Using a type attribute to stop the contents of a script tag from being executed as JavaScript is a well understood technique, and although the list of type names that cause script to be executed varies from browser to browser, finding one that won't cause execution is not hard.

More interesting is the question of the semantics. It is my view that the semantics of the script element are essentially inert, like a div or span element, while RoToRa's view is that it affects the semantics of the content. Looking at the specs, it is not easy to resolve. HTML 4.01 says very little about the semantics of the script element, concentrating solely on its functionality.

The HTML5 spec is not much better, but it does say "The element does not represent content for the user.". I don't know what to make of that. Saying what an element doesn't do is not very helpful. If it implies that its contents are semantically "hidden" from the user, such that the its contents are not semantically part of contents of the containing code element, then this technique should not be used.

If, however, it means that no new semantics are introduced by the script element, then there doesn't appear to be any problem.

I can't find any evidence of a script element being semantically required to contain script, as RoToRa suggests, and while it might be considered common-sense to infer that, that's not how HTML semantics works.

In many ways, this approach is really about trying to find a way to do validly what the XMP element does in browsers anyway, but is not valid. XMP was very nearly made valid in HTML5 but just missed out. The editor described it as a [tough call](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12235#c12). Using the script element like this meets that requirement, but it seems nevertheless to be controversial. If you are uncomfortable with whatever semantics you feel are being applied is this approach, I would suggest that you don't use it.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to misuse the `script` element like this.

Comment: @RoToRa - In what way? It's valid. What real world problems does it cause?

Comment: Buggy/older browsers trying to execute it despite the `type` attribute? But more importantly it breaks semantics. What's next? `blockquote` for indenting and `table` for layout?

Comment: @RoToRa - There are plenty of examples on the web of script elements that don't contain javascript. Many frameworks rely on them and the fact that browsers won't try to execute them. As for the semantics, the `<code>` element meets the semantics requirements.

Comment: Exactly, the frameworks execute the script, because that's what the `script` element is for: executing script, not displaying it. Putting a `div` around a table layout doesn't stop it being a table layout.

Comment: @RoToRa - Nope, sometimes the frameworks just use the script elements for containing data. And putting a div around a table doesn't stop it from being a table, agreed. Doesn't stop the div from being a div either though.